# ARC declared property attributes - understanding

Tags: objective-c, properties, uml, automatic-ref-counting

Is it correct, that the `strong` attribute refers to an object composition, and the `weak` attribute refers to object aggregation, in terms of [UML notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#UML_notation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

I would say they are similar but different.

In Objective-C the raison d'être for weak references is usually described as a way to manually break what would otherwise be a retain cycle - this is needed as ARC does not (at least currently) support collecting such cycles. This is not really a use of aggregation.

You will also see them used for things like notifications where one object will send notifications to another as long as the latter exists. This might be seen as closer to aggregation, but is really "do something if the target exists" and not "don't kill the target if I die".

You can of course use weak references in Obj-C to implement an aggregation, but you might not get exactly the behaviour you expect.

Consider the C++ example from your reference:

```
class Professor;

class Department
{
   ...
private:
   // Aggregation
   Professor* members[5];
   ...
};
```

Which in Objective-C might be:

```
@interface Department

@property (weak) NSArray *members;
...

@end
```

When the C++ object is destroyed the *array* is also destroyed but the elements of the array are not. However in Objective-C the array is not destroyed either - an `NSArray` always maintains strong references to its members, so they stay around. You could of course design weak collections for Objective-C.

Comment: Declaring an array property as `weak` is not good idea. Once you assign an `NSArray` instance there and you do not store it anywhere else, you lose it and probably lose all contained object too.

Comment: Also, there are weak collections in Foundation. `NSHashTable` and `NSMapTable` are `weak` equivalents for `NSMutableSet` and `NSMutableDictionary`. But you still need to have `strong` references to them to keep them alive.

Comment: there are good reasons to use `weak`.. but any object referred to by a `weak` property slot must have a `strong` reference to it somewhere else in your program.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with difference between composition and aggregation, because both of them are used in both cases.

Examples from your link:

- In case of one-to-one:

  1. Car has `strong` reference to Carburetor.
  2. Carburetor has `weak` reference to Car.
- In case of one-to-many:

  1. Pond has `strong` reference to an array of Ducks.
  2. The array holds `strong` reference to each contained Duck.
  3. Duck has `weak` reference to pond.

In both cases there is owner with `strong` reference and owned objects with `weak` back-references.

So I would say that `strong` and `weak` are two endpoints of that UML connection line representing composition or aggregation.